# Angular - displaying nested collections, using the `group-by` filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm playing around with the [angular `group-by` filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)- I've tried to replicate their example, it's not working yet. What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ez4Lcs9RI6GIps5bV9Qi?p=preview)

Here's the html:

```
 <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

      <accordion-group is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups | groupBy: 'title'">
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{ key }}
          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.isOpen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        {{group.content}}
        <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="group in value">
        list item: {{group.list}}
      </li>
    </ul>

      </accordion-group>

    </accordion>
  </div>
```

Here's the js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      content: 'content 1',
      isOpen: true
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      content: 'Content 2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      content: 'Content 3'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      content: 'content 4'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      content: 'content 5'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item3'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      list: 'item1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      list: 'item2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      list: 'item1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      list: 'item2'
    },    
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      list: 'item1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      list: 'item1'
    }
  ];
});
```

Maybe I'm approaching this wrong, perhaps my `groups` in the js file is funky, what I'm trying to do is basically have a collection that has one `title` and one `content` entry for each collection, but multiple `list` entries (basically multiple bullet points). But it seems from their example what I am doing should work?

What I'd prefer to do in the js file is something like this:

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      content: 'content 1',
      item: 'bullet point 1',
      isOpen: true
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      content: 'Content 2'
      item: 'bullet point 1',
      item: 'bullet point 2'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      content: 'Content 3',
      item: 'bullet point 1',
      item: 'bullet point 2',
      item: 'bullet point 3'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      content: 'content 4',
      item: 'bullet point 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      content: 'content 5',
      item: 'bullet point 1',
      item: 'bullet point 2'
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like you have angular filters in your module dependancies list:

change:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
```

to:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
```

---

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.groups = [{
    title: 'title 1',
    content: 'content 1',
    isOpen: true
  }, {
    title: 'title 2',
    content: 'Content 2'
  }, {
    title: 'title 3',
    content: 'Content 3'
  }, {
    title: 'title 4',
    content: 'content 4'
  }, {
    title: 'title 5',
    content: 'content 5'
  }, {
    title: 'title 1',
    list: 'item1'
  }, {
    title: 'title 1',
    list: 'item2'
  }, {
    title: 'title 1',
    list: 'item3'
  }, {
    title: 'title 2',
    list: 'item1'
  }, {
    title: 'title 2',
    list: 'item2'
  }, {
    title: 'title 3',
    list: 'item1'
  }, {
    title: 'title 3',
    list: 'item2'
  }, {
    title: 'title 4',
    list: 'item1'
  }, {
    title: 'title 5',
    list: 'item1'
  }];
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Dynamic angular accordion with nested angular collection - Test</h1>

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

      <accordion-group is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups | groupBy: 'title'">
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{ key }}
          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.isOpen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="group in value">
            list item: {{ group.list }}
          </li>
        </ul>

      </accordion-group>

    </accordion>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Now it's not opening the first one on `page load`, and it's not showing `{{group.content}}` . [Here's a new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAdm72sPkGYsrPFDt5RQ?p=preview)

Comment: If you change that `{{ group.content }}` to just `{{ group }}` you will see that group is just an object with an `isOpen` property in that scope. `content` is undefined.

Comment: ah ok, I see it, interesting. I fixed the `{{group.content}}` by putting `<p ng-repeat="group in value">` in front of it. Now the only thing is it does not open the first one anymore on `pageload`. [here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAdm72sPkGYsrPFDt5RQ?p=preview)

Comment: This is a new requirement and you shouldn't expect this to go under the scope of this question. You should mark this as answered and ask a new one if you have further questions. But also of course try to fix it yourself first.

Comment: @jan Ah, ok. Start a new one even if it's something that was working but is now not? not sure of protocol here, I would imagine that should be part of the original. Thanks.

Comment: @jan Well, thanks for the snarky comment, it was working before I tried to do the above :D You're making assumptions, and being nasty and judgmental. In my response to you I was just trying to figure out protocol here. I'm appreciative of DTing for his assistance. However jan, I give you five stars in the the how to be entirely discouraging and demotivating category. Congratulations. It's comments like yours above that make stackoverflow sometimes very unfun to use.

Comment: "it was working before I tried to do the above". We can't know what the code looked like before you edited it. You might have removed something entirely, and @DTing still answered your question perfectly. If you have an example that does what you want, compare them and see what you missed. Or POST that example if you need help figuring out what's different, but the protocol would be for you to try to figure it out yourself first. And if you look at my comments objectively and without taking offense, you'll see that it's not snarky but sound advice.